# Moving an outgoing message to trash

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have a script that receives messages from a particular sender
And sends them on to another email
the code is:

```
function send() {
  let addressForSearch = 'aaaaaa@mail.com' // the senders email
  let emailForTransfer = 'bbbbbb@mail.com' // the final recipients email
  let messages = GmailApp.search(`from:${addressForSearch}`)
  if (messages.length > 0) {
    messages.forEach(function (m) {
      let message = m.getMessages()[0]
      let subject = message.getSubject()
      let body = message.getBody()
      let attachments = message.getAttachments()
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailForTransfer, subject, '', {
        htmlBody: body,
        attachments: attachments
      })
    })
  }
}
```

The question is, how do I delete (move to trash) the messages I sent through the script and are now in 'is sent'?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Usually questions with all uppercase title are not well received, please avoid them. To delete / send to trash a message you have to use `GmailApp`. If you need further help please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, what i did is, i inserted a hidden Uuid in the message, so i get a way to search for the specific email. here is the code

```
function redirect() {
  let emailForTransfer = '****123@gmail.com' // the final recipients email
  let addressForSearch = GmailApp.search(`from:***123@gmail.com is:unread`) //the senders email
  if (addressForSearch.length > 0) {
    for (let formessage of addressForSearch) {
      let message = formessage.getMessages()[0]
      let subject = message.getSubject()
      let body = message.getBody()
      let attachments = message.getAttachments()
      var searchTerm = Utilities.getUuid();
      var uidText = '<span style="color:transparent; display:none !important; height:0; opacity:0; visibility:hidden; width:0">' + searchTerm +  '</span>';
      GmailApp.sendEmail (emailForTransfer, subject, '', {
        htmlBody: body + uidText,
        attachments: attachments
        });
        Utilities.sleep(2000);
        GmailApp.search(searchTerm)[0].moveToTrash()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: shoel Do you need php to javascript function. I made one

Comment: I tried writing it. `https://jsfiddle.net/navnathjadhav/ah2uLz95/`

Answer (score 0):

After sending the emails, you can create another search for the email sent to the final recipient and use [GmailApp:moveThreadsToTrash(threads)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#movethreadstotrashthreads).

Add this to your code:

```
 let threads = GmailApp.search(`to:${emailForTransfer}`)
  if (thread.length > 0) {
    GmailApp.moveThreadsToTrash(threads);
  }
```

Also, please do note that MailApp has limited functions (Only getRemainingDailyQuota() and sendEmail()). See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)

Comment: thanks for answering, but i dont want that all emails i send to the recipient should be moved to trush. I want that only the emails thats sents Automatically from a particular sender should go, and the mails that i send directly from my account should stay in the outgoing emails